# What is the meaning of last scene of s20e06 with Caitlyn Jenner?

Tags: south-park

In the last scene of South Park, episode 6 of season 20, a bunch of memberberries drops one of their own into a martini glass with gin & tonic, which then gets served to Caitlyn Jenner. She sips from the glass, but doesn't eat the berry or the olive, and responds to the server "Buckle up, buckaroos!"

Why did the memberberries gang up on one of their own and drop him into that martini glass? How is Caitlyn Jenner involved in the election? What would be the effect of the memberberry being eaten by her?

Comment: I *think* it was supposed to be a cliffhanger (not sure, though).

Comment: Well yea, it's the last scene of the episode. But I think maybe I missed some details about who Caitlyn is supposed to represent in the real world's events, or something about memberberries. So I'm asking if we should know anything about that scene.

Comment: I think Caitlyn is simply Caitlyn--Matt and Trey just really hate her.

Comment: There are still four episodes to go in this season. Why not simply watch them and then see if you've got questions?

Comment: @BCdotWEB because, as I've already said in my other comment, I think that I may have missed some important points about memberberries or the role of Caitlyn's character.

Answer (score 1):

According to the episode 5, everybody was voting for Garrison because the memberberries were feeding them propoganda. We always see Randy go throught breakthroughs, like in the first season on how to avoid the volcanic rupture and one of my favourites was when he realised that Butters was feeding everyone his sperm. Likewise he was also able to deduce that memberberries can influence people's behaviour. How they do it, and who is behind is something we would have to wait and see. But maybe they influence people when they are ingested in that case Caitlyin got under control of the memberberries. Mike Pence, Caitlyin's real life counterpart is often regarded as superior to him and it can be said that some of his Trump's supporters are wooed by him only. So, my guess is that Caitlyin would now take a more active role in the election and help get more votes for Garrison. Obviously, Garrison would say things no sane candidate would say but Caitlyin would defend him (like Mike Pence does).

As for the behaviour of memberberries I think it was for comedic relief, they act adorable but their behaviour is akin to that of a mafia. Why they did it to one of their 'own'? Because that memberberry was severely tortured by Randy and was incapacitated .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the memberberries were created by someone that wants Mr. Garrison to win the election (maybe it's JJ Abrams). When the memberberries enter Caitlyn's tonic to force her to make Mr. Garrison President.

Comment: Thank you for assisting the community. Ideas for framing an answer may include describing your sources along with a synopsis of what they said, adding links to the resources and visuals you’ve found, or giving us the rationale behind your ideas and conclusions. I hope you enjoy participating.